# how to get whole string including space using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery and I want to show FullName of a Student in popup, but I'm getting only first name, e.g. if I want to show `Abc Xyz` it is only showing `Abc` - it is taking only the first word but not the word after the space.

My code is as given below:

```
<a data-dialog-href="#" id="delete-@item.StudentId" href="#" data-studentName=@item.StudentName>Click Here</a>
```

```js
jQuery('body').on('click', '[data-dialog-href]', function (e) {
    var studentName = jQuery(this).attr('data-studentName');
    alert('Student Name : ' + studentName);
}
```

How can I get whole string including space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should get everything as its written. Check this fiddle ---> https://jsfiddle.net/r63tunsd/ <----

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because you need to wrap the value of the attribute in your HTML in quotes, otherwise the first space reached will delimit the value. Try this:

```html
<a data-dialog-href="#" id="delete-@item.StudentId" href="#" data-studentName="@item.StudentName">Click Here</a>
```

Also note that you should use the `data()` method to retrieve the value:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-dialog-href]', e => {
  var studentName = $(e.target).data('studentName');
  console.log('Student Name : ' + studentName);
});
```